# How to add more features into drywall sheet program?

Tags: python

So this is the basic drywall calculator code I have:

```
def  drywall_sheets_required(width,depth,height,useScrap=False):
 if useScrap==False:
   sheetSize1=(4*8)
   surfacearea1=(width*depth)
   surfacearea2=(width*height)
   surfacearea3=(height*depth)
   TotalArea=surfacearea1+surfacearea2+surfacearea2+surfacearea3+surfacearea3
   ss1=surfacearea1/sheetSize1
   TSS1=ss1
   ss3=surfacearea2/sheetSize1
   TSS2=ss3+ss3
   ss5=surfacearea3/sheetSize1
   TSS3=ss5+ss5
   Dsum=TSS1+TSS2+TSS3
   print(TotalArea)
   print("You need",int(Dsum)+1,"drywall sheets for the room")
```

Basically it calculates the area of the four walls and ceiling and divides it by the area of the drywall which is 32. However I to expand this script like this:

```
def  drywall_sheets_required(width,depth,height,sheetSize=(4,8),useScrap=True):
```

If useScrap is true, then any remaining piece of drywall can be reused. When useScrap is false, then all scrap pieces have to be thrown away. For my current code, if the total area is not an integer, it adds one. So I guess this means that useScrap is false.

Also, is there a way I can change the orientation of the drywall sheet? The standard size is (4,8), but if I change it to (8,4) will it made a significant difference?

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten it a bit; I figure that more control is needed over how small a piece of scrap can be used:

```
from math import ceil

DEBUG = True
if DEBUG:
    def debug_print(x): print(x)
else:
    def debug_print(x): pass

def drywall_sheets_per_surface(surface_width, surface_height, div_sheet_width_by, div_sheet_height_by, sheet_width, sheet_height):
    """
    Calculate the number of sheets of drywall needed to finish a rectangular surface

    Params same as for drywall_sheets_per_room
    """
    w = ceil(float(div_sheet_width_by ) * surface_width  / sheet_width ) / div_sheet_width_by
    h = ceil(float(div_sheet_height_by) * surface_height / sheet_height) / div_sheet_height_by
    debug_print('Width: {}\'  Height: {}\'  -> {} sheets ({}\') wide x {} sheets ({}\') high = {} sheets'.format(surface_width, surface_height, w, w*sheet_width, h, h*sheet_height, w*h))
    return w*h

def drywall_sheets_per_room(room_width, room_length, room_height, div_sheet_width_by=5, div_sheet_height_by=2, sheet_width=8, sheet_height=4):
    """
    Calculate the number of sheets of drywall needed to finish a room

    Given:
        room_width            float: room width in feet
        room_length           float: room length in feet
        room_height           float: room height in feet
        div_sheet_width_by    int:   number of times you are willing to split the width  of a sheet
        div_sheet_height_by   int:   number of times you are willing to split the height of a sheet
        sheet_width           float: sheet width in feet
        sheet_height          float: sheet height in feet

    Returns:
        float: number of sheets required
    """
    sides   = 2. * drywall_sheets_per_surface(room_length, room_height, div_sheet_width_by, div_sheet_height_by, sheet_width, sheet_height)
    ends    = 2. * drywall_sheets_per_surface(room_width,  room_height, div_sheet_width_by, div_sheet_height_by, sheet_width, sheet_height)
    ceiling =      drywall_sheets_per_surface(room_length, room_width,  div_sheet_width_by, div_sheet_height_by, sheet_width, sheet_height)
    debug_print('Total of {} sheets required.'.format(sides + ends + ceiling))
    return sides + ends + ceiling
```

The default parameters assume that you will not reuse any scrap less than 16" wide (to match wall stud spacing) or 24" high (half a sheet-height). You can change the minimum piece size by modifying the `div_sheet_x_by` parameters; setting them both to 1 means "whole sheets only". Room length should be measured perpendicular to the ceiling joists, which will usually be the longer room dimension.